# Function returns integer in the console and undefined when injecting in innerHTML Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, input

You can see the essence of my question here:

http://pirania.eu/test/kalkulator/templates/oklejanie-aut.html

I put it online on purpose, because when I use JSFiddle, Codepen etc. the view in console is different (it doesn't get the integer).

After clicking first input, I have undefined in console and 0 in the place of the final price. After changing the second input, it's the same. Both of them are correct. But, after the third click (in the order, one of the 3 radio buttons here) I can see integer in the console, but the "undefined" appears in the place of price. How is that possible? parseInt or anything similar to that doesn't work.

HTML:

```
  <main>
      <section id="content">
        <h2>Oklejanie aut - reklama, zmiana koloru itd.</h2>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>segment</th>
              <th>zmiana koloru</th>
              <th>reklama na całości</th>
              <th>reklama 3/4 auta</th>
              <th>reklama 1/2 auta</th>
              <th>reklama tył auta</th>
              <th>projekt indywidualny<br><span>(cena za m</span><sup>2</sup><span>)</span></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr class="b">
              <td>B (np. Opel Corsa)</td>
              <td class="price zmiana-koloru">3 000,00 zł</td>
              <td class="price na-calosci">2 930,00 zł</td>
              <td class="price trzy-czwarte">2 060,00 zł</td>
              <td class="price jedna-druga">1 420,00 zł</td>
              <td class="price tyl">400,00 zł</td>
              <td class="price projekt-indywidualny">130,00 zł</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="c">
              <td>C (np. Opel Astra)</td>
              <td class="price zmiana-koloru">3 400,00 zł</td>
              <td class="price na-calosci">3 220,00 zł</td>
              <td class="price trzy-czwarte">2 100,00 zł</td>
              <td class="price jedna-druga">1 560,00 zł</td>
              <td class="price tyl">410,00 zł</td>
              <td class="price projekt-indywidualny">130,00 zł</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="d">
              <td>D (np. Ford Mondeo)</td>
              <td class="price zmiana-koloru">3 700,00 zł</td>
              <td class="price na-calosci">3 580,00 zł</td>
              <td class="price trzy-czwarte">2 500,00 zł</td>
              <td class="price jedna-druga">1 760,00 zł</td>
              <td class="price tyl">450,00 zł</td>
              <td class="price projekt-indywidualny">130,00 zł</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="van">
              <td>VAN (np. Citroen Berlingo)</td>
              <td class="price zmiana-koloru">3 800,00 zł</td>
              <td class="price na-calosci">3 500,00 zł</td>
              <td class="price trzy-czwarte">2 400,00 zł</td>
              <td class="price jedna-druga">1 750,00 zł</td>
              <td class="price tyl">450,00 zł</td>
              <td class="price projekt-indywidualny">130,00 zł</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="bus">
              <td>BUS (np. Citroen Jumper L1H2)</td>
              <td class="price zmiana-koloru">6 600,00 zł</td>
              <td class="price na-calosci">5 500,00 zł</td>
              <td class="price trzy-czwarte">3 000,00 zł</td>
              <td class="price jedna-druga">2 100,00 zł</td>
              <td class="price tyl">600,00 zł</td>
              <td class="price projekt-indywidualny">130,00 zł</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="naczepa">
              <td>NACZEPA (np. L – 13,60 m)</td>
              <td class="price zmiana-koloru">11 000,00 zł</td>
              <td class="price na-calosci">10 500,00 zł</td>
              <td class="price trzy-czwarte">7 900,00 zł</td>
              <td class="price jedna-druga">5 250,00 zł</td>
              <td class="price tyl">950,00 zł</td>
              <td class="price projekt-indywidualny">130,00 zł</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <p>Zmiana koloru – folia carwrapping:
          <ul>
            <li>cena dotyczy folii białej i czarnej mat;</li>
            <li>folia kolor, metalic, perła + 15%;</li>
            <li>folia carbon, szczotkowana + 65%.</li>
          </ul>
        </p>
        <p>Reklama na aucie: cena z projektem, dla folii wylewanej wysokoplastycznej z laminatem.</p>
        <form action="" method="post">
          <label for="segment">Wybierz segment:</label>
          <select name="segment" id="segment">
            <option value="choose">Kliknij, aby wybrać</option>
            <option value="b">B (np. Opel Corsa)</option>
            <option value="c">C (np. Opel Astra)</option>
            <option value="d">D (np. Ford Mondeo)</option>
            <option value="van">VAN (np. Citroen Berlingo)</option>
            <option value="bus">BUS (np. Citroen Jumper L1H2)</option>
            <option value="naczepa">NACZEPA (np. L – 13,60 m)</option>
          </select><br><br>
          <label for="option">Wybierz opcję:</label>
          <select name="option" id="option">
            <option value="choose">Kliknij, aby wybrać</option>
            <option value="zmiana-koloru">zmiana koloru</option>
            <option value="na-calosci">reklama na całości</option>
            <option value="trzy-czwarte">reklama 3/4 auta</option>
            <option value="jedna-druga">reklama 1/2 auta</option>
            <option value="tyl">reklama tył auta</option>
            <option value="projekt-indywidualny">projekt indywidualny</option>
          </select><br><br>
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Wybierz typ folii:</legend>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="foil" id="matte" value="matte"><span>Biała i czarna mat</span>
            </label><br>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="foil" id="color" value="color"><span>Kolor, metalic, perła + 15%</span>
            </label><br>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="foil" id="carbon" value="carbon"><span>Carbon, szczotkowana + 65%</span>
            </label>
          </fieldset>
          <p>Cena:&nbsp;<span id="output">0</span><span>&nbsp;zł</span></p>
          <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Dodaj">
        </form>
      </section>
    </main>
```

JS:

```
//get variable of the place of the price's display
let spanPrice = document.getElementById('output');
function cars() {
    // get variable of the segment type input
    let segment = document.getElementById("segment");
    //get variable of the option type input
    let option = document.getElementById("option");
    //get variables of the type type input
    let matte = document.getElementById("matte");
    let color = document.getElementById("color");
    let carbon = document.getElementById("carbon");

    //get string, leave only integers, cut two last characters, return an integer
    function stringToInt(s) {
        s = s.replace(/\D/g, '').slice(0, -2);
        return parseInt(s);
    }

    //add 15% to a value
    function colorFoil(e) {
        e = e + e * 0.15;
        return e;
    }

    //add 65% to a value
    function carbonFoil(d) {
        d = d + d * 0.65;
        return d;
    }

    //declaration of variables of rows
    let rowB = document.querySelector('tr.b');
    let rowC = document.querySelector('tr.c');
    let rowD = document.querySelector('tr.d');
    let rowVan = document.querySelector('tr.van');
    let rowBus = document.querySelector('tr.bus');
    let rowNaczepa = document.querySelector('tr.naczepa');

    //the mighty function
    function bigOne() {
        //count dependencies
        function count() {
            //if the chosen value from first input is b
            if (segment.value === "b") {
                //if the chosen value from the second input is zmiana koloru
                if (option.value === "zmiana-koloru") {
                    //return innerhtml of the zmiana coloru class that is nested in row B
                    return rowB.querySelector('.zmiana-koloru').innerHTML;
                } else if (option.value === "na-calosci") {
                    return rowB.querySelector('.na-calosci').innerHTML;
                } else if (option.value === "trzy-czwarte") {
                    return rowB.querySelector('.trzy-czwarte').innerHTML;
                } else if (option.value === "jedna-druga") {
                    return rowB.querySelector('.jedna-druga').innerHTML;
                } else if (option.value === "tyl") {
                    return rowB.querySelector('.tyl').innerHTML;
                } else {
                    return rowB.querySelector('.projekt-indywidualny').innerHTML;
                }
            } else if (segment.value === "c") {
                if (option.value === "zmiana-koloru") {
                    return rowC.querySelector('.zmiana-koloru').innerHTML;
                } else if (option.value === "na-calosci") {
                    return rowC.querySelector('.na-calosci').innerHTML;
                } else if (option.value === "trzy-czwarte") {
                    return rowC.querySelector('.trzy-czwarte').innerHTML;
                } else if (option.value === "jedna-druga") {
                    return rowC.querySelector('.jedna-druga').innerHTML;
                } else if (option.value === "tyl") {
                    return rowC.querySelector('.tyl').innerHTML;
                } else {
                    return rowC.querySelector('.projekt-indywidualny').innerHTML;
                }
            } else if (segment.value === "d") {
                if (option.value === "zmiana-koloru") {
                    return rowD.querySelector('.zmiana-koloru').innerHTML;
                } else if (option.value === "na-calosci") {
                    return rowD.querySelector('.na-calosci').innerHTML;
                } else if (option.value === "trzy-czwarte") {
                    return rowD.querySelector('.trzy-czwarte').innerHTML;
                } else if (option.value === "jedna-druga") {
                    return rowD.querySelector('.jedna-druga').innerHTML;
                } else if (option.value === "tyl") {
                    return rowD.querySelector('.tyl').innerHTML;
                } else {
                    return rowD.querySelector('.projekt-indywidualny').innerHTML;
                }
            } else if (segment.value === "van") {
                if (option.value === "zmiana-koloru") {
                    return rowVan.querySelector('.zmiana-koloru').innerHTML;
                } else if (option.value === "na-calosci") {
                    return rowVan.querySelector('.na-calosci').innerHTML;
                } else if (option.value === "trzy-czwarte") {
                    return rowVan.querySelector('.trzy-czwarte').innerHTML;
                } else if (option.value === "jedna-druga") {
                    return rowVan.querySelector('.jedna-druga').innerHTML;
                } else if (option.value === "tyl") {
                    return rowVan.querySelector('.tyl').innerHTML;
                } else {
                    return rowVan.querySelector('.projekt-indywidualny').innerHTML;
                }
            } else if (segment.value === "bus") {
                if (option.value === "zmiana-koloru") {
                    return rowBus.querySelector('.zmiana-koloru').innerHTML;
                } else if (option.value === "na-calosci") {
                    return rowBus.querySelector('.na-calosci').innerHTML;
                } else if (option.value === "trzy-czwarte") {
                    return rowBus.querySelector('.trzy-czwarte').innerHTML;
                } else if (option.value === "jedna-druga") {
                    return rowBus.querySelector('.jedna-druga').innerHTML;
                } else if (option.value === "tyl") {
                    return rowBus.querySelector('.tyl').innerHTML;
                } else {
                    return rowBus.querySelector('.projekt-indywidualny').innerHTML;
                }
            } else {
                if (option.value === "zmiana-koloru") {
                    return rowNaczepa.querySelector('.zmiana-koloru').innerHTML;
                } else if (option.value === "na-calosci") {
                    return rowNaczepa.querySelector('.na-calosci').innerHTML;
                } else if (option.value === "trzy-czwarte") {
                    return rowNaczepa.querySelector('.trzy-czwarte').innerHTML;
                } else if (option.value === "jedna-druga") {
                    return rowNaczepa.querySelector('.jedna-druga').innerHTML;
                } else if (option.value === "tyl") {
                    return rowNaczepa.querySelector('.tyl').innerHTML;
                } else {
                    return rowNaczepa.querySelector('.projekt-indywidualny').innerHTML;
                }
            }
        }

        count();

        function settings() {
            //get NodeList of the radio buttons type of input
            let radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
            //make an array of it
            let radioButtonsArray = [...radioButtons];

            //count the result depending on radio button checked
            let result = function listen() {
                //for every radio button from the radioButtonsArray
                radioButtonsArray.some(function () {
                    //if the first, matte one is checked
                    if (radioButtonsArray[0].checked === true) {
                        // console.log('matte checked');
                        console.log(stringToInt(count()));
                        //return the result unchanged
                        return stringToInt(count());
                        //if the second one, color is checked
                    } else if (radioButtonsArray[1].checked === true) {
                        // console.log('color checked');
                        console.log(colorFoil(stringToInt(count())));
                        //return the result + 15%
                        return colorFoil(stringToInt(count()));
                        //if the third one, carbon is checked
                    } else if (radioButtonsArray[2].checked === true) {
                        // console.log('carbon checked');
                        console.log(carbonFoil(stringToInt(count())));
                        //return the result + 65%
                        return carbonFoil(stringToInt(count()));
                    }
                });
            };
            if (segment.value !== "choose" && option.value !== "choose" && (matte.checked === true || color.checked === true || carbon.checked === true)) {
                // display the result of the function in the proper place, as a summary of the counting operation
                spanPrice.innerHTML = result();
            }
        }

        settings();
    }

    //if the value of the input is changed
    segment.addEventListener("change", function () {
        //call the mighty function
        bigOne();
        console.log(bigOne());
    });
    option.addEventListener("change", function () {
        console.log(bigOne());
        bigOne();
    });
    matte.addEventListener("change", function () {
        console.log(bigOne());
        bigOne();
    });
    color.addEventListener("change", function () {
        console.log(bigOne());
        bigOne();
    });
    carbon.addEventListener("change", function () {
        console.log(bigOne());
        bigOne();
    });

}

cars();
```

Comment: **Wow**, way too much code here, you should only insert relevant code in your post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, AdrienBrunelat and Adelin. First of all, I'm a "she". Second of all, I am quite a n00b when it comes to JS and I'd really love to do this, but I don't know how, as I think everything here is relevant - without even smallest part, the whole function wouldn't work. So my question is, could you please give me some hints on how should I improve it looks? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `console.log(stringToInt(count()));` shows `undefined` => then `stringToInt(count())` returns `undefined` => either one of `count` or `sringToInt` returns `undefined` etc. This it what you need to do. Follow the breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you are seeing on console 'undefined' because you are printing bigOne() that doesnt return nothing

second, inside `function settings()` the function that print `console.log(stringToInt(count()));` is defined as a variable named result (`let result = function listen() {<your code>}`) that has never been called so just call `result()` at the end of settings and will do something

i hope that helps you

Comment: Thank you so much. Very valuable hint.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case - here's the working function. Thanks everyone.

HTML didn't change.

JS:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    "use strict";

    //get variable of the place of the price's display
    let spanPrice = document.getElementById('output');


    function cars() {
        // get variable of the segment type input
        let segment = document.getElementById("segment");
        //get variable of the option type input
        let option = document.getElementById("option");
        //get variables of the type type input
        let matte = document.getElementById("matte");
        let color = document.getElementById("color");
        let carbon = document.getElementById("carbon");

        //get string, leave only integers, cut two last characters, return an integer
        function stringToInt(s) {
            s = s.replace(/\D/g, '').slice(0, -2);
            return parseInt(s);
        }

        //add 15% to a value
        function colorFoil(e) {
            e = e + e * 0.15;
            return e;
        }

        //add 65% to a value
        function carbonFoil(d) {
            d = d + d * 0.65;
            return d;
        }

        //declaration of variables of rows
        let rowB = document.querySelector('tr.b');
        let rowC = document.querySelector('tr.c');
        let rowD = document.querySelector('tr.d');
        let rowVan = document.querySelector('tr.van');
        let rowBus = document.querySelector('tr.bus');
        let rowNaczepa = document.querySelector('tr.naczepa');

        //get NodeList of the radio buttons type of input
        let radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
        //make an array of it
        let radioButtonsArray = [...radioButtons];

        //the mighty function
        function bigOne() {
            //count dependencies
            function count() {
                //if the chosen value from first input is b
                if (segment.value === "b") {
                    //if the chosen value from the second input is zmiana koloru
                    if (option.value === "zmiana-koloru") {
                        //return innerhtml of the zmiana coloru class that is nested in row B
                        return rowB.querySelector('.zmiana-koloru').innerHTML;
                    } else if (option.value === "na-calosci") {
                        return rowB.querySelector('.na-calosci').innerHTML;
                    } else if (option.value === "trzy-czwarte") {
                        return rowB.querySelector('.trzy-czwarte').innerHTML;
                    } else if (option.value === "jedna-druga") {
                        return rowB.querySelector('.jedna-druga').innerHTML;
                    } else if (option.value === "tyl") {
                        return rowB.querySelector('.tyl').innerHTML;
                    } else {
                        return rowB.querySelector('.projekt-indywidualny').innerHTML;
                    }
                } else if (segment.value === "c") {
                    if (option.value === "zmiana-koloru") {
                        return rowC.querySelector('.zmiana-koloru').innerHTML;
                    } else if (option.value === "na-calosci") {
                        return rowC.querySelector('.na-calosci').innerHTML;
                    } else if (option.value === "trzy-czwarte") {
                        return rowC.querySelector('.trzy-czwarte').innerHTML;
                    } else if (option.value === "jedna-druga") {
                        return rowC.querySelector('.jedna-druga').innerHTML;
                    } else if (option.value === "tyl") {
                        return rowC.querySelector('.tyl').innerHTML;
                    } else {
                        return rowC.querySelector('.projekt-indywidualny').innerHTML;
                    }
                } else if (segment.value === "d") {
                    if (option.value === "zmiana-koloru") {
                        return rowD.querySelector('.zmiana-koloru').innerHTML;
                    } else if (option.value === "na-calosci") {
                        return rowD.querySelector('.na-calosci').innerHTML;
                    } else if (option.value === "trzy-czwarte") {
                        return rowD.querySelector('.trzy-czwarte').innerHTML;
                    } else if (option.value === "jedna-druga") {
                        return rowD.querySelector('.jedna-druga').innerHTML;
                    } else if (option.value === "tyl") {
                        return rowD.querySelector('.tyl').innerHTML;
                    } else {
                        return rowD.querySelector('.projekt-indywidualny').innerHTML;
                    }
                } else if (segment.value === "van") {
                    if (option.value === "zmiana-koloru") {
                        return rowVan.querySelector('.zmiana-koloru').innerHTML;
                    } else if (option.value === "na-calosci") {
                        return rowVan.querySelector('.na-calosci').innerHTML;
                    } else if (option.value === "trzy-czwarte") {
                        return rowVan.querySelector('.trzy-czwarte').innerHTML;
                    } else if (option.value === "jedna-druga") {
                        return rowVan.querySelector('.jedna-druga').innerHTML;
                    } else if (option.value === "tyl") {
                        return rowVan.querySelector('.tyl').innerHTML;
                    } else {
                        return rowVan.querySelector('.projekt-indywidualny').innerHTML;
                    }
                } else if (segment.value === "bus") {
                    if (option.value === "zmiana-koloru") {
                        return rowBus.querySelector('.zmiana-koloru').innerHTML;
                    } else if (option.value === "na-calosci") {
                        return rowBus.querySelector('.na-calosci').innerHTML;
                    } else if (option.value === "trzy-czwarte") {
                        return rowBus.querySelector('.trzy-czwarte').innerHTML;
                    } else if (option.value === "jedna-druga") {
                        return rowBus.querySelector('.jedna-druga').innerHTML;
                    } else if (option.value === "tyl") {
                        return rowBus.querySelector('.tyl').innerHTML;
                    } else {
                        return rowBus.querySelector('.projekt-indywidualny').innerHTML;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (option.value === "zmiana-koloru") {
                        return rowNaczepa.querySelector('.zmiana-koloru').innerHTML;
                    } else if (option.value === "na-calosci") {
                        return rowNaczepa.querySelector('.na-calosci').innerHTML;
                    } else if (option.value === "trzy-czwarte") {
                        return rowNaczepa.querySelector('.trzy-czwarte').innerHTML;
                    } else if (option.value === "jedna-druga") {
                        return rowNaczepa.querySelector('.jedna-druga').innerHTML;
                    } else if (option.value === "tyl") {
                        return rowNaczepa.querySelector('.tyl').innerHTML;
                    } else {
                        return rowNaczepa.querySelector('.projekt-indywidualny').innerHTML;
                    }
                }
            }

            count();

            // display the result of the function in the proper place, as a summary of the counting operation
            function final() {
                radioButtonsArray.some(function () {
                    //if every input is on place
                    if (segment.value !== "choose" && option.value !== "choose" && (matte.checked === true || color.checked === true || carbon.checked === true)) {
                        //if the first, matte one is checked
                        if (radioButtonsArray[0].checked === true) {
                            //return the result unchanged
                            return spanPrice.innerHTML = stringToInt(count());
                            //if the second one, color is checked
                        } else if (radioButtonsArray[1].checked === true) {
                            //return the result + 15%
                            return spanPrice.innerHTML = colorFoil(stringToInt(count()));
                            //if the third one, carbon is checked
                        } else if (radioButtonsArray[2].checked === true) {
                            //return the result + 65%
                            return spanPrice.innerHTML = carbonFoil(stringToInt(count()));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            final();
        }

        //if the value of the input is changed
        segment.addEventListener("change", function () {
            //call the mighty function
             bigOne();
        });
        option.addEventListener("change", function () {
            bigOne();
        });
        matte.addEventListener("change", function () {
             bigOne();
        });
        color.addEventListener("change", function () {
             bigOne();
        });
        carbon.addEventListener("change", function () {
             bigOne();
        });


    }

    cars();
});
```